# How to add text annotations with python in dm-script

Tags: python, annotations, dm-script

How do I add a text annotation with python in [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) (*Edit* ... in Version 3.4.0)?

---

I want to add some text to images by using python in the GMS python environment. Therefore I want to use text annotations.

I can create a text annotation by using `DM.NewTextAnnotation()`. But the returned `DM.Py_Component` object does not have any `ComponentAddChild...()` methods. So I can create text annotations but I cannot add them.

There also is a `DM.Py_Component.AddNewComponent(type, f1, f2, f3, f4)` method. I can create text annotations with that (using `type = 13`). But I can only specify the position with the parameters `f1` to `f4`. Using a string argument raises a `TypeError`. There is a `DM.Py_Component.GetText()` and several font manipulation methods but no `DM.Py_Component.SetText()`. So I can create text annotations which are already appended to the parent component but without text. And I cannot set the text.

The `dm-script` docs also talk about a `Component::ComponentExternalizeProperties()` which lets me assume that there is a `TagGroup` in the background of each component. Is there any way to manipulate that, even though there is no `DM.Py_Component.ExternalizeProperties()` in the python module.

---

So my question is: What is the intended way of adding text annotations to images? Is there any way of either adding annotations to components or setting the text of an added annotation?

Comment: Yes, these commands were missing in initial releases of the Python API and are essential. Please upgrade to the latest GMS version.

Comment: I've added a hybrid-script example to my answer in case you cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned missing commands have been added with the most recent release **GMS 3.4.3**.
Without them, there is no way of adding components except with some creative hybrid-coding.

With the commands, the correct example is:

```py
testImg = DM.GetFrontImage()
img_disp = testImg.GetImageDisplay(0)
textComp = DM.NewTextAnnotation(0, 0, 'test new text annotation', 15)  
img_disp.AddChildAtEnd(textComp)

# Cleanup 
del img_disp
del testImg
```

and for changing text of an existing text component (type 13):

```py
testImg = DM.GetFrontImage()
img_disp = testImg.GetImageDisplay(0)

nSubComp = img_disp.CountChildren()
for index in range(nSubComp):
    comp = img_disp.GetChild(index)
    if ( comp.GetType() == 13 ):
        comp.TextAnnotationSetText( 'Other text' )

# Cleanup 
del img_disp
del testImg
```

---

---

If you need to do this with a version prior GMS 3.4.3 you can work around the missing command by calling a DM script from your Python script as in this example:

```py
annotext = 'This is the annotation'
testImg = DM.GetFrontImage()

# Build a DM script as proxy
dmScript = '// This is a DM script' + '\n'
dmScript += 'imageDisplay disp = ' + testImg.GetLabel() + '.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)' + '\n'
dmScript += 'component anno = NewTextAnnotation( 0, 0, "'
dmScript += annotext 
dmScript += '", 15)' + '\n'
dmScript += 'disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( anno )' + '\n'
#print( dmScript )

# Run the DM script
DM.ExecuteScriptString( dmScript )

# Cleanup 
del testImg
```